# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ArticlesController#import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

I am importing and exporting the csv file to create my articles and exporting them in the blog.
but I am facing the following error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}, missing required keys: [:id]`  .
Also I have put require 'csv' in application.js.
Can anyone solve this error and explain about this so I do not get this again.

Here is my files -
index.html.erb

```html
<h3>Import Articles</h3>
  <%= form_tag import_articles_path, multipart: true do %>
  <div>
     <%= link_to "Export CSV",article_path(@article) %> // error is getting generated here on exporting
  </div>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
   <%= submit_tag "Upload Articles" %>
  <% end %>
```

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    @articles = Article.includes(:user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @articles }
      format.atom
      @articles = Article.order(:name).page params[:page]
      format.csv { send_data @articles.to_csv } // on importing error is getting here
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def self.import(file)
      CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Article.create! row.to_hash
      end
    end
  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |article|
        csv << article.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When using fenced code blocks you need to put the fences (```) on their own line. Its usually better to actually just write out the `class Whatever` as it both makes for an easy to reproduce example and having the context makes the code easier to read.

Comment: As for the actual error - if you use byebug or pry or something to step into your code you should see that `@article` is most likely nil. Which makes sense as you don't have a single article in an index action. I don't really understand why you expect this to work - I mean you can't link to something that you haven't even created yet.

Comment: Thanks I got that.

Comment: Please post your route file

Comment: the issue has been resoled. thanks @Matthew